# Image cropper doesn't work within nested foreach

Tags: umbraco7

I have a problem in Umbraco 7. I'm using a nested Multiple Node Tree Picker, but the GetCropUrl doesn't work. The crop function is ok, I've already used it.

```
@{
    if (CurrentPage.HasValue("artists"))
    {

        var artistList = CurrentPage.artists.ToString().Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var artistCollection = Umbraco.Content(artistList);
        foreach (var artist in artistCollection)
        {
            if (artist.HasValue("coverImages"))
            {
                var coverImagesList = artist.coverImages.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                var coverImagesCollection = Umbraco.Media(coverImagesList);

                foreach (var coverImage in coverImagesCollection.RandomOrder().Take(1).Where("Visible"))
                {
                   <img src="@coverImage.GetCropUrl(305, 195)"/>
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I changed the code and I started to use Id.
When I use this:

```
foreach (var coverImage in coverImagesCollection)
   <p>@coverImage.Id</p>
   <img src="@Umbraco.TypedMedia(1105).Url"/>
}
```

I got back the the image id from @coverImage.Id, and the image is working.

When I use this:

```
foreach (var coverImage in coverImagesCollection)
   <img src="@Umbraco.TypedMedia(coverImage.Id).Url"/>
}
```

The image is still good.

After I'm cropping with fix id.

```
foreach (var coverImage in coverImagesCollection)
   <img src="@Umbraco.TypedMedia(1105).GetCropUrl(305, 195)"/>
}
```

Working, but then:

```
foreach (var coverImage in coverImagesCollection)
   <img src="@Umbraco.TypedMedia(coverImage.Id).GetCropUrl(305, 195)"/>
}
```

I got an error:

**'Umbraco.Web.Models.PublishedContentBase' does not contain a definition for 'GetCropUrl'**
How is that possible?

Comment: How does it not work? Is there an error message, or does it simply not crop the image?

Comment: No error message, just simply an empty field. With .Url i see the picture.

Comment: An empty field? Are you sure a coverImage is found at all?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. When I change to @coverImage.Url i got the image

Comment: Sorry, you already said that. I'm at a loss then.

Answer (score 2):

I've got an answer from Umbraco forum. He said coverImage.Id is dynamic, so I need to try this, and it worked perfectly:

```
foreach (var coverImage in coverImagesCollection)
   <img src="@Umbraco.TypedMedia((int)coverImage.Id).GetCropUrl(305, 195)"/>
}
```